# Term reference on node edit to ALL vocabularies

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have about ten vocabularies and my content will be tagged with mostly one term of ANY of them.

It would be fine to let the editor choose the vocabulary on node edit form.

Is there yet a module or patch for that situation?   It would be the core taxnonomy module, right?

A workaround would be to mount all the ten vocs into the "11th", the root one. (They have been created as mindmaps and splitted for sake of overview and because I want to use taxonomy menu and keep each one small)

Answer (score 0):

The [Vocabulary reference](http://drupal.org/project/vocabulary_reference) module might help you, but it doesn't even have a dev release.

A more involved solution would require adding a term reference field for each vocabulary, then placing a "controlling" list field on top of them, with an allowed value for each vocabulary.

You could then dynamically show and hide the right term reference field using the [Conditional Fields](http://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module.

The module handles required fields, so you would be sure that one term is always selected.

Comment: thx, that brought me on track. voc ref would be fine for small vocs as only select field is usable. The Cond.field approach is too ugly and I looked further. Soon I got to entity reference and for now I use a select field and the child terms are indented, so it is usable.